# Deploy Angular 7 app made with visual studio 2017 template to IIS

Tags: angular, iis, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.2

I'm new to .net core and angular. I made a simple app and was looking for a decent guide on how to deploy it to IIS. I'm using .net core 2.2 and angular 7.

Most of what I could find is describing the deployment steps for pure angular applications. I tried to run dotnet publish on a solution and then point IIS to the output, but with no luck. I also tried to move the content of ClientApp\dist folder to the wwwroot folder, but there was no positive effect.

I believe there is something that should be done with index.html or web.config file.

Does anyone knows where to find a working step by step guide, or maybe could share their experience on how to make this work?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: I deploy apps on IIS. Do you get any error? What's happening?

Comment: Hi. When I execute dotnet publish and point IIS to the produced output - the website is not starting. It also gives no error. I tried to follow the answer below, but then it starts giving the error that I mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this one a bit randomly.

I tried to use not CLI dotnet publish but VS2017 publish to folder function (which should be essentially the same in my world, but I'll check files tomorrow and update this comment if there was some differences).

Then I pointed an IIS to the target folder and added users IUSR, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS with full control permissions on Security tab.

And... that just worked.

Comment: Was able to make it work from the command line. So it looks like permissions fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe there is something that should be done with index.html or
>   web.config file.

In the `web.config` you set Angular routes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

If you are deploying it in the sub folder not root. Then set the base href of your app in the `index.html`.

For example:

```
<base href="/myapp">
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I changed a config file as you described. Now iis throwing an error like "There was an error while performing this operation" pointing to the web.config file. Looks like url rewrite module is needed, but I have installed the dotne-hosting bundle, so it should be there...